# add custom icon into text field within the border flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add custom icon inside my text filed border I used the propriety prefixIcon but my custom Icon is from IconData type and the prefixIcon  Expected an widget this the way I added the custom icon https://medium.com/codechai/how-to-use-custom-icons-in-flutter-834a079d977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Custom Icon is an IconData type while `Icon()` is a widget which takes an IconData

have you tired using it like this

```
prefixIcon: Icon(YourCustomIcon),
```

Comment: I did the same but in wrong class when u said the same answer I noticed that, however thanks alot